# Как перед однозначным числом в дате/времени ставить цифру 0?

Tags: python, python-3.x, дата, время, datetime

Всем привет.
Использовал модуль datetime и столкнулся с проблемой, что мне выводит время с миллисекундами, т.е вот:
"19:09:40.003307"
Как мне убрать миллисекунды и получить время в формате "HH:MM:SS"?
Использовал так:

```
current_time = datetime.now().time() # В начале кода
str(current_time) # Использование
```

Comment: Такое чуво люди разучились пользоваться Гуглом. Проще на форуме спрашивать

Comment: хороший повод поговорить с умными людьми.этож хорошо

Comment: А какая тут вообще связь между заголовком и самим вопросом?

Answer (score 3):

[strftime() and strptime() Format Codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime('04.02.19 1:56:22.900552', '%y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S.%f').strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```

## 01:56:00

```
d = datetime.now()  # 2020-07-08 20:19:51.948950
d.strftime('%H:%M:%S')  # 20:19:51
d2 = d.time()  # 20:19:51.948950
d2.strftime('%H:%M:%S')  # 20:19:51
```

Comment: Как насчет добавить в ответ пример с: `datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')` и/или `datetime.now().time().strftime('%H:%M:%S')`?

Comment: ну вы уже все добавили, просто там сказано про какой-то ноль перед однозначным числом, чего может не быть в datetime.now(), это и хотел показать

Comment: Добавил то я в комментарии, но лучше если дополнительная инфа будет в самом ответе :)

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нужно убрать их именно в строковом представлении, можно воспользоваться вполне стандартной работой со строками

```py
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> current_time = datetime.now().time() # В начале кода
>>> str(current_time) # Использование
'19:31:31.871461'
>>> str(current_time)[:str(current_time).rfind('.')]
'19:31:31'
```

Но лучше обратить внимание на формат вывода даты ([ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1150560/361777) пользователя [vadim vaduxa](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/208915/vadim-vaduxa))